# Changes coming in Version 1.1 of the Twitter API in iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, version

I am using twitter API version V1.0 for my new iphone application .I am successfully able to do this using twitters v1.0 of the API and all works perfectly. Simply making a request to http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=userid retrieves all the information that I require.
since v1.0 has been deprecated and V1.1 requires authentication for each request, I get a bad authorization error (HTTP response status: 400)using this API.
 What are the Changes i need to do in my appication .how to generate OAuth request headers,Do i need register my application ?How can i get authentication for new version?

I hope the above makes sense and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-slrequest

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth

u can get the authentication using following method:

NSString *base64 = @"Basic NFRLWGlZY3l1aHJ4OVJaUWI5RW5BOmdVMXlvcVV6YzBNZUhUQmFXdVRZU2NtZHlIWDFOZXhwZmxqRE16bm01aw==";
    //oauth_consumer_secret,oauth_consumer_key
    NSURL *urlAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"]];

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:urlAPI];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:base64];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"];

[request setPostValue:@"client_credentials" forKey:@"grant_type"];
```

In response u will get the authtoken for your application like this

{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMddRQAAAAAAXRP6Axur1RS%2Fv9YFtJ7TijyPAGo%3DpmNowwOGf3dZTHDiH2gnCcv7qNIyGZcyV2IW5YFTBs"}